# Neo4j user defined procedure not shown

Tags: java, c#, neo4j, jar

i have compiled a “user-defined” procedure (.jar file) for “Neo4j” and placed it in the plugins folder as specified in their manual,

Yet it does not recognize my procedure after restarting the server, I have followed their guidelines and yet it still doesn’t work.

I have little experience with eclipse or java as I am a C# programmer,

Can someone break-down the process of creating a java project and deploying a (.jar) into “Neo4j” for anyone who is in a similar situation as me?

Comment: Please, give us more details, otherwise it will be hard to help you. Is the code accessible somewhere ? What steps have you followed ?Is there something in the debug.log at the restart ?

Comment: @logisima Hi i managed to resolve the problem, thank you!